# Security of dynamic compilation of code on the fly

Tags: java, security

I want to create a website where people are able to run java code through a text box and I compile and run the code on the server and give them the results. Just like they do on tutorialspoint.com/compile_java_online.php. Now that being said I am trying to determine the best way to make it so they do not use malicious code or if they do use malicious code it does not hurt anything. What would be the best approach here? Use a specific container that is only used for the code execution? And if they blow up that container it just spin up another one? I am just trying to think of options for this.

Comment: Matt Godbolt (the creator of [GodBolt](https://godbolt.org/)) has a talk about how he created his compiler tester [link](https://youtu.be/bSkpMdDe4g4?t=47m35s). For security he ran everything on Amazon AWS inside a Docker instance. This allowed him to dynamically scale his setup and keep everything locked away. He had a separate server containing all the compilers and important bits that he didn't want anyone to potentially be able to touch.

Comment: Hmmm interesting, ill look into this. Yeah I think the only way for me to secure it is use external containerization so they cant do much. And then also limit the text boxes.